# Correct XPath After Incorrect Recording

Tags: selenium, xpath

Good afternoon,  I am new to automated testing and would greatly appreciate any steers on how to find the correct XPath for a control by which the Selenium IDE or Selenium builder has seemingly incorrectly identified the control.

Automotive category – Selenium IDE Recorded XPath ID Relative:

```
//div[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/section/form/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ng-include/div/div/span
```

- XPath Position:

  //ng-include/div/div/span

Car and Vehicle Hire Subcategory – Selenium IDE Recorded XPath ID 
- XPath ID Relative:

```
//div[@id='content']/div/div/div/div/section/form/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/ng-include/div[2]/div/ng-include/div/div/span
```

- XPath Position:

  //div[2]/div/ng-include/div/div/span

Sourcecode Sample

```
  <label>Categories *</label>
                <div class="validation-message ng-hide" ng-show="createOfferForm.selectedCategoriesTree.$wasInvalidOnBlur || createOfferForm.selectedCategoriesTree.$invalidated">
                    Please select at least one category

                </div>
                <br/>
                <script type="text/ng-template" id="category-template.html">
                    <div class="list-group-item box-list-item" ng-class="{selected: category.Selected}" ng-click="toggleSelect(category, listCategories);">

                        <div>

                            <span class="box-title truncate category">{{category.Title}}</span>

                            <span class="box-icon" ng-init="category.expanded = false" ng-show="showChevron(category)">

                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" ng-click="category.expanded = !category.expanded; $event.stopPropagation();" ng-show="category.expanded"></i>

                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" ng-click="expand(category); category.expanded = !category.expanded; $event.stopPropagation();" ng-hide="category.expanded"></i>

                            </span>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div ng-show="category.expanded">

                        <div class="sub-level" ng-repeat="category in category.listCategories">

                            <ng-include src="'category-template.html'"></ng-include>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </script>
                <div class="pure-g">
                    <div class="pure-u-1">
                        <i>Available</i>
                        <div class="categories-list box-list" tabindex="5">
                            <span ng-if="!listCategories.length" ng-hide="overlaySelected"><strong>The domain has to be selected in order to see the list of categories!</strong></span>
                            <div class="loading" ng-show="overlaySelected">
                                <div class="spinner-wrapper">
                                    <span class="spinner-text">LOADING</span>
                                    <span class="spinner"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="level" ng-repeat="category in listCategories" ng-model="category">
                                <ng-include src="'category-template.html'"></ng-include>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="pure-g mtH1">
                    <div class="pure-u-1">
                        <i>Selected</i>
                        <div class="categories-selected unload">
                            <ul class="box-list" ng-cloak ng-model="selectedCategoriesTree" name="selectedCategoriesTree" not-empty ng-was-invalid-on-blur tabindex="6" ng-class="{invalid: createOfferForm.selectedCategoriesTree.$wasInvalidOnBlur || createOfferForm.selectedCategoriesTree.$invalidated}">
                                <li ng-repeat="categoriesRow in selectedCategoriesTree" ng-cloak class="list-group-item">
                                    <label class="box-list-item" ng-repeat="category in categoriesRow">
                                        <div>
                                            <span class="box-title">{{ category.Title }}</span>
                                            <span class="box-icon"><i class="fa fa-times" ng-click="removeSelected(category.Id)"></i></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question? Please have a read through [ask].

Comment: Well it's probably identified the element as it was at the time. Welcome to the world of AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure regarding what elements you are trying to map, either way have you considered mapping by css?

for instance, if you are trying to map the span below:

```
<span ng-if="!listCategories.length" ng-hide="overlaySelected"><strong>The domain has to be selected in order to see the list of categories!</strong></span>
```

try using the following css path:

```
cssSelector = ".categories-list box-list > span"
```

Just a quick tip -

EDIT
Why I believe you should avoid using xpath when you can:

Performance difference between css/xpath selectors are basically nil except when you are dealing with it in old versions of IE. So don't take that in account when choosing one... Although, the main reason why I would go for CSS selectors is readability. It is a common language between your dev and ux guys as well...

Comment: "DOM uses css to interact with elements" really?!?! "Xpath lacks performance vs css" do you have anything to back that up?!?!

Comment: was tired and didnt express myself correctly... trying to be buyest towards css... edited....